# Radio Button on Checked if condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-checked

I am having a structure something like this

```
<div>
 <span>Employer</span>
 <input type="radio" value="Current">
</div>
<div>
 <span>Employer</span>
 <input type="radio" value="Previous">
</div>
<div><button>Add Employer</button>


<div>
 <span>Employer</span>
 <input type="radio" value="Current">
</div>
<div>
 <span>Employer</span>
 <input type="radio" value="Previous">
</div>
<div><button>Add Employer</button>
```

1. I select Employer as Current.
2. I went on to add the new employer.
3. In new employer radio button it should have default selection as radio button "previous"

Am try to work on such conditions. If any one can please help in Checked If condition on dynamically created radio button please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value to the button using `ng-value`. Something like this:

```
 <input type="radio" ng-value="true" value="Previous">
```

Comment: all right.. let me give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion. Shall update on the code you suggested.

Comment: but then if I ng-repeat the input which has ng-value="true". I will add ng-value true to that inputa again. How do I deal with that then?